# Redefining a command with arguments inside another comand sometimes does not work

Tags: ifthenelse, csname

I try to generate a `\law` command that behaves differently depending on the settings. `\setlaw` changes the behaviour differently. It seems to work for the first two cases. However, when trying to put brackets around the argument it stops working (for the min-case):

```
\documentclass[parskip=full]{scrlttr2}

\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}

\usepackage{ifthen}
    
\newcommand{\Absatz}[1]{Absatz\,#1}
\newcommand{\Satz}[1]{Satz\,#1}

\newcommand{\setlaw}[1]
    {\ifthenelse{\equal{\detokenize{#1}}{\detokenize{long}}}
        {\renewcommand{\Absatz}[1]{Absatz\,\csname#1\endcsname}
         \renewcommand{\Satz}[1]{Satz\,\csname#1\endcsname}         
        }
        {\ifthenelse{\equal{\detokenize{#1}}{\detokenize{short}}}
            {\renewcommand{\Absatz}[1]{Abs.\,\csname#1\endcsname}
             \renewcommand{\Satz}[1]{S.\,\csname#1\endcsname}
            }
            {\ifthenelse{\equal{\detokenize{#1}}{\detokenize{min}}}
                {\renewcommand{\Absatz}[1]{(\csname#1\endcsname)}
                 \renewcommand{\Satz}[1]{\csname#1\endcsname}
                }
                {}
            }
        }
        
    }

\newcommand{\law}[4][BGB]{\S\,#2 \Absatz{#3} \Satz{#4} #1}

\begin{document}

    \law{123}{4}{2}
    \setlaw{short}
    \law{123}{4}{2}
    \setlaw{min}    
    \law{123}{4}{2}
    
\end{document}
```

The result should be:

§ 123 Absatz 4 Satz 2 BGB

§ 123 Abs. 4 S. 2 BGB

§ 123 (4) 2 BGB

Comment: #1 is the argument of the outer command, you want ##1

Comment: why detokenize  min? that does nothing useful

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Yes it does. It might be hard to see in the code, though. It puts brackets around the `\Absatz` argument. The `\,` for `\Satz` for the `min`-case is wrong, you are right.

Comment: no. some of the detokenize do something but `\detokenize{long}` could be replaced by `long` for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `\csname#1\endcsname` should be `\csname##1\endcsname`.
2. `\csname...\endcsname` is completely wrong, as you want to print the law numbers, not use (undefined) commands based on them.

Here's a much simpler approach.

```
\documentclass[parskip=full]{scrlttr2}

%\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\usepackage{sourcesanspro}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\str_new:N \l_mrc_law_satz_str

\NewDocumentCommand{\setlaw}{m}
 {
  \str_set:Nn \l_mrc_law_satz_str { #1 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\Absatz}{}
 {
  \str_case:Vn \l_mrc_law_satz_str
   {
    {long}{Absatz}
    {short}{Abs.\@}
    {min}{}
   }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\Satz}{}
 {
  \str_case:Vn \l_mrc_law_satz_str
   {
    {long}{Satz}
    {short}{S.\@}
    {min}{}
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\law}[4][BGB]{\S\,#2 \Absatz\,#3 \Satz\,#4 #1}

\setlaw{long} % initialize

\begin{document}

Long: \law{123}{4}{2}

\setlaw{short}
Short: \law{123}{4}{2}

\setlaw{min}    
Min: \law{123}{4}{2}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! You also seem to have missed that the `\Absatz` argument needs to be placed into brackets for the `min`-case. Learning from your approach and trying `{min}{(\@)}` for `\Absatz` strangely puts the argument after (!) the brackets. Why is that? And how can this be fixed? I want the result for Min to be: `§ 123 (4) 2 BGB`

Comment: I realize I had made a mistake in the `\law` command. I forgot to put the `#2` and `#2` in curly brackets. I have fixed it now. It should show what I indeded and also that I need the argument (if only for the `min`-case that needs to put text before and after the argument).

Comment: Correction for first comment: I needed to put `\NewDocumentCommand{\Absatz}{m}` and then `{min}{(#1)}`. But still the numbers stays out of the brackets... That is so strange... Why is that?

Comment: I realized my mistake. In my test setup I had forgotten to update the `\law`-definition with `\Absatz{#3}`. Thanks for your help as always!